# Is there any function could make date minus bigint type in Athena?

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

select user_id,first_event_date,(date(max(event_date)) - rnk) date_on
from
(select event_date,user_id,first_event_date,row_number() over(partition by user_id order by first_event_date desc) rnk
from retention_user_selected)
GROUP BY user_id, first_event_date
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65vv4.png)

This would show error : '-' cannot be applied to date, bigint

Answer (score 0):

Try using intervals:

```
date(max(event_date)) - rnk * interval '1 day'
```